# Geb: browser is running slow in grails environment

Tags: performance, grails, browser, webdriver, geb

I use Geb in a grails environment and without. If I run geb in a seperated project the browsers are a lot faster. If I run the same tests in the **grails environment they are between 9 and 10 times slower**.
This **doesn't happen to a remote webdriver instance**.

It hits chrome and firefox aswell. I use geb-spock 0.9 (it occured on 0.7.2 too). And usually the newest webdriver (2.32.0-2.33.0).

Did someone else have similar problems? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that your grails app is memory hungry and when you run it together with geb and webdriver in one jvm it hits a point when it needs to garbage collect the memory all the time? I personally never had problems caused by grails slowing geb down, but I've seen grails apps that get extremely slow because of insufficient memory allocation using jvm args.

Comment: i think you have few memory in your PC.

Comment: I think erdi might be right. I'll investivste that.